# Zabbix trigger tracking EventID

Tags: windows, events, zabbix

Good afternoon. There is a need to track the occurrence of events in the windows event log.
Microsoft-Windows-CertificateServicesClient-Lifecycle-System/Operational
Created the data items:
eventlog[Microsoft-Windows-CertificateServicesClient-Lifecycle-System/Operational,,,,1002|1003|1004|1006]

When creating a trigger with the following text:
{Template Windows - Eventlog 2016:eventlog[Microsoft-Windows-CertificateServicesClient-Lifecycle-System/Operational,,,,1002|1003|1004|1006].logeventid(1003)}=1&{Template Windows - Eventlog 2016:eventlog[Microsoft-Windows-CertificateServicesClient-Lifecycle-System/Operational,,,,1002|1003|1004|1006].nodata(5m)}=0

An error appears:
Invalid parameter "/1/expression": incorrect expression starting from "{Template Windows - Eventlog 2016:eventlog[Microsoft-Windows-CertificateServicesClient-Lifecycle-System/Operational,,,,1002|1003|1004|1006].logeventid(1003)}=1&{Template Windows - Eventlog 2016:eventlog[Microsoft-Windows-CertificateServicesClient-Lifecycle-System/Operational,,,,1002|1003|1004|1006].nodata(5m)}=0".

Tell me, what is my mistake?